# NaCl allows decryption with the same public key as for encryption

Tags: encryption, public-key, decryption

I followed the description here:

[Public-key authenticated encryption: crypto_box](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/box.html)

and created an example that encrypts a message with Bob's public key and signs it with Alice's secret key :

```
cipher = crypto_box(secret_string, nonce, bob_pk, alice_sk);
```

The cipher text can be decrypted and verified with Bob's secret key and Alice's public key:

```
message = crypto_box_open(cipher, nonce, alice_pk, bob_sk);
```

However, the message can **also** be decrypted with Bob' public key and Alice's secret key:

```
message = crypto_box_open(cipher, nonce, bob_pk, alice_sk);
```

This is somehow unexpected. I couldn't find much documentation for the crypto box. What is the math behind it?

My full code to reproduce:

```
#include <crypto_box.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <randombytes.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::string alice_pk;
    std::string alice_sk;
    std::string bob_pk;
    std::string bob_sk;
    std::string nonce;
    std::string cipher;
    std::string message;

    std::string secret_string = "my secret string";

    unsigned char buffer[crypto_box_NONCEBYTES];

    randombytes((unsigned char*)buffer, crypto_box_NONCEBYTES);
    nonce.assign((const char*)buffer, (size_t)crypto_box_NONCEBYTES);

    alice_pk = crypto_box_keypair(&alice_sk);
    bob_pk   = crypto_box_keypair(&bob_sk);

    cipher = crypto_box(secret_string, nonce, bob_pk, alice_sk);

    message = crypto_box_open(cipher, nonce, bob_pk, alice_sk);  

    std::cout << message << std::endl;

    message = crypto_box_open(cipher, nonce, alice_pk, bob_sk);  

    std::cout << message << std::endl;


}
```

Comment: > Selected primitive  
> crypto_box is curve25519xsalsa20poly1305, a particular combination of Curve25519, Salsa20, and Poly1305 specified in "Cryptography in NaCl". This function is conjectured to meet the standard notions of privacy and third-party unforgeability.

Comment: That is where in the linked page it has a description of the crypto used. Mr. Denis' explanation is correct, since Curve25519 is an ECDH primitive in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alice and Bob's keys are used to compute a **shared** key.

Both parties compute the same key, which is used both encryption and decryption.

This is a traditional, hybrid encryption system.

Using only asymmetric cryptography for encryption would be painfully slow.

As a mitigation, the sender can create an ephemeral key pair, deleted right after the message has been encrypted. See ECIES or libsodium's `crypto_box_seal()` construction.

Comment: So why exactly can I decrypt the message with the same public key used for encryption?

Comment: The same key can be computed either from `(Alice PK, Bob SK)` or `(Bob PK, Alice SK)`. This is the key actually used for encryption, and decryption.

Comment: So this is ECDH with some symmetric cipher then? On the website, they mention not a single bit about DH.

Comment: Yes, `crypto_box()` is ECDH using X25519, and encryption using salsa20poly1305.